# French freelancer moving to Australia

Tags: australia, freelance, french-citizens

I currently work as a freelancer in France, and I plan to move to Australia. I intend to continue to work for my clients (who are based in Europe), but only for a few months as I will ultimately look for a role within a company. So my question is: can I continue to work as a freelancer with my French status for 5-6 months (while living in Australia), or do I need to register as a freelancer in Australia (which means the contracts I have need to be updated)?

PS: visa is not an issue; I am on a partner visa.

Comment: You may need to get an ABN: https://abr.gov.au/For-Business%2c-Super-funds---Charities/Applying-for-an-ABN/ABN-entitlement/